# Bash/Sed/Awk - parsing CSV from column ==x until column==x again

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I've got a rather large set of CSV's that I need to parse. Most of it is extremely easy, however I've got some 'group' objects with embedded objects that I need to extract correctly.

The file looks something like this

```
Test_GroupA,Group,-,-,-,-,NodeA,,-,
,,,,,,NodeB,,,
,,,,,,NodeC,,,
,,,,,,NodeD,,,
,,,,,,NodeE,,,
Test_GroupB,Group,-,-,-,-,NodeA,,-,
,,,,,,NodeB,,,
,,,,,,NodeC,,,
,,,,,,NodeX,,,
,,,,,,NodeE,,,
,,,,,,NodeF,,,
```

So, as you can see, I need something along the lines of:

```
    awk -F"[,|]" '{if ($2=="Group")
then - pseudo code->
print "create group",$1
print "add member in $7 to group found in $1 of first row"
continue until you reach next $2=="Group"), then loop
```

This is perplexing me greatly :)

Edit::
It seems a lot of the values are somewhat bogus and contain '-' when they're blank instead of just being ,,

Something like

```
    sed 's/\,\-\,/\,\,/g'
```

should replace them I'd think, however I think I need a leading wildcard.

New example:

```
grp-ext-test-test,Group,-,-,-,-,Net_10.10.10.10,,-,
,,,,,,Net_10.101.10.10,,,
,,,,,,ws-ext-test-10.102,,,
,,,,,,ws-ext-test-10.103,,,
,,,,,,ws-ext-test-10.104,,,
,,,,,,ws-ext-test-10.105,,,
,,,,,,ws-ext-test-10.106,,,
,,,,,,ws-ext-test-10.107,,,
,,,,,,ws-ext-test-10.108,,,
,,,,,,ws-ext-test-10.108,,,
```

Running the new string on it only produces:

```
create group grp-ext-test-test
```

Comment: can you paste what output do you want?

Comment: Having it look like what Scrutinizer created is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this and adapt as required..

```
awk -F, '$2=="Group"{g=$1; print "create group",g}{print "add " $7 " to " g}' file
```

Output:

```
create group Test_GroupA
add NodeA to Test_GroupA
add NodeB to Test_GroupA
add NodeC to Test_GroupA
add NodeD to Test_GroupA
add NodeE to Test_GroupA
create group Test_GroupB
add NodeA to Test_GroupB
add NodeB to Test_GroupB
add NodeC to Test_GroupB
add NodeX to Test_GroupB
add NodeE to Test_GroupB
add NodeF to Test_GroupB
```

---edit---
To check if the contents of $7 are valid you could try something like:

```
awk -F, '$2=="Group"{ g=$1; print "create group",g } $7!="-"{print "add " $7 " to " g}' file
```

Comment: I'm seeing a couple of issues in my real files, I'll update in a few minutes once I figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I think I need a sed string infront of it...a lot of the values seem to contain ,-, instead of just ,, for being blank. Any way to do that via awk?

Comment: Reason being is that I get a lot of "add - to groupX"

Comment: You could test if `$7` consists of alphanumerical characters. I added this to my post..

Comment: That doesn't seem to work...Not entirely sure why though. It's only picking up about 2-3% of the group members now (it seems to grab all of the groups themselves though). I'll add a new example, one sec

Comment: It's improved, but still doesn't seem to catch the 'ws-ext' pieces of the new example, I would assume because they contain '-'